# Checkout a new master avoiding commited changes in local master (in GIT)

Tags: git, git-checkout, hotfix

I cannot find the right answer maybe because I don't know how to make the right question, but I will try to explain myself:

To make a new feature I forgot to make a new branch and I was working and commiting (not pushing) to my local master branch since then. The new feature is not finished yet (and indeed can breaks production), but now I need to do some hotfixes and push them to production (master), so...

Is there any way to checkout/clone another "master" to my local computer and work in there in such a way that I can push the hotfixes changes without pushing the new feature? I know could do it in another computer but is not possible for me now.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, checkout a new branch from where you are, and then reset master.

```
git checkout -b feature
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the commit from which you started to make your feature commits. `git log master --oneline` or `git reflog master` could help. Assume it's commit xxx.

Rename current master to feature, via `git branch -M master feature`.

Make a new master from that commit xxx, via `git branch master xxx`.